# I want to remove FORCED DEV MODE OFF ENABLED notification from my theme

Tags: wordpress, redux-framework

I'm working on a theme with redux-framework and I want to remove this notification from theme options.
[image]

Edit :
This is a demo link : https://demo.redux.io/wp-admin/admin.php?page=_options&tab=0

Comment: please provide more information like its showing in admin end or front end any URL of the page anything else so we can review it did you try with CSS or not?

Comment: @R.K.Bhardwaj its showing in admin-end. Actually i am working on a local so i can`t provide link.

Comment: need to check theme options files or find the class name  on the div into files

Comment: @R.K.Bhardwaj Thanks!! i`ll try

Comment: see my recent edit in questions.

Comment: you want something like this : https://prnt.sc/k544ln

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174790/discussion-between-varinder-sohal-and-r-k-bhardwaj).

Answer (score 2):

Add this selector in your style
`.redux-container #redux-header .display_header span.redux-dev-mode-notice{ display:none}`

Answer (score 1):

please use this filter

```
$this->args = apply_filters( "redux/args/{$this->args['opt_name']}", $this->args );
```

the code should be like this

```
add_filter( 'redux/args/OPTION_NAME', 'disabled_dev_mode', 10, 1 );
function disabled_dev_mode( $args ) {
    $args['dev_mode'] = false;
    return $args;
}
```